# covariance of cross product of two vectors

Tags: cross-product, covariance

I have two independent vectors in 3D and know the covariance matrix of each. What will be the covariance of cross products of above vectors.

In particular what will be the covariance of cross product if each of vectors covariance matrixes are just a diagonal matrix or even scaled by a scalar identity matrix?

Actually I need to come with covariance matrix for vectors cross product to use it in Kalman filter.

Comment: Do you assume a Gaussian distribution? The cross product is a polynomial of degree 2, so it will no longer be Gaussian.

Comment: Yes the distribution was Gaussian. And your message  LutzL sounds like a bad news for Kalman filter... Maybe some Gaussian approximation could be made (maybe as a function of current vector values)?

Comment: Study the distribution of higher moments of Gaussian distributions, this also applies here. You may need a reformulation of your problem to get the filtering linear in the state variables.